# RecyclerView flickering line while scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm working on my first Android app and implemented a RecyclerView to scroll through some items.
I followed the following [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Gm3eMG8KqI).

I'm using a Huawei P20 Pro (physical device) to test the program, and i noticed that there is a flickering line while scrolling through the items. (On the emulator, use a Google Pixel 3 and there is no noticeable flickering)

[White flickering line that appears during scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPwZU.png)

I implemented the adapter as:

```
package com.example.recyclerviewexample

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.test_3.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.example_item.view.*

class ExampleAdapter(private val exampleList: List<ExampleItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.example_item,
            parent,
            false)
        return ExampleViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = exampleList[position]

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageResource)
        holder.textView1.text = currentItem.text1
        holder.textView2.text = currentItem.text2
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = exampleList.size

    class ExampleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.image_view //image_view is the id of the image! (same: itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view))
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.text_view_1
        val textView2: TextView = itemView.text_view_2
    }
}
```

Also, i uploaded my code to [Github](https://github.com/milmario/AndroidApp_Test_1) so you can try it out yourself.
As I'm very new to android studio, I really have no clue what's going on and would highly appreciate your help.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MaliActivity">


  <include

    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_mali"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/search_list"
        android:layout_width="399dp"
        android:layout_height="633dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="331dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:queryHint="Search for a resource ">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>


   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think it is a problem with the layout, you can change to Relative layout. Check how I have implemented mine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed to LinearLayout (RelativeLayout didn't fix it.
In addition, i had to change the layout_width to a fixed value (400dp), than the flickering stopped (match_parent leads to the flickering)... I actually liked the constraint layout but it seems like I'm forced to use the LinearLayout here. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome, the constraint is better for responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Layout file. the `match_parent` on the Layout height property. Change it to `wrap_content`.

In my case the issue was each item in the `recyclerview` occupied the whole screen and this helped. It could be the same for you.